# Discord.js how to seach channel from client

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a discord.js event called userUpdate.js which has parameters `client,oldUser, newUser`

i tried

```
 var log = client.guilds.channels.find(ch => ch.name.includes('log')) ;
        if (!log) return;
        if (!log.permissionsFor(client.user).has(["SEND_MESSAGES","EMBED_LINKS"])) return;
```

but i get is channels is not defined

```
log.send("message here");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got undefined bacause you try find channel in guild collection.

for discord v11 version

```js
 let log = client.channels.find(ch => ch.name.includes('log')) ;
        if (!log) return;
        if (!log.permissionsFor(client.user).has(["SEND_MESSAGES","EMBED_LINKS"])) return;
```

for discord v12 version

```js
     let log = client.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name.includes('log')) ;
        if (!log) return;
        if (!log.permissionsFor(client.user).has(["SEND_MESSAGES","EMBED_LINKS"])) return;
```

Better use channel ID for that

```js
    let logChannel = client.channels.get("ID")
    if (!logChannel) return;
    if (!logChannel.permissionsFor(client.user).has(["SEND_MESSAGES","EMBED_LINKS"])) return;
```

> For v12 replace `client.channels.get("ID")` to `client.channels.cache.get("ID")`

Comment: issue is idk the id of channel so i need to find channel by name multi guild bot

Comment: So you need map guild for this or filter client channels, because `find` method return only 1 channel.

Comment: if i\`ts production bot for many servers, `includes('log')` can be many channels, like `login, catalog, blog`

Comment: yah i removed login ,blog and other to reduce code here its all in my bots code
yah i need to filter channel and get only 1 channel at a time